# Como hacer un registro de varios radio buttons a la vez en laravel

Tags: laravel, radiobutton, test, radiogroup

Estoy haciendo un sistema el cual permita generar y contestar test, pero me encuentro en el problema de que no se como hacer que me diferencie las opciones de cada pregunta y a su vez guarde todas las respuestas en una tabla, ya que a como lo tengo solo me guarda la respuesta de la ultima pregunta.

Vista:

```html
<!-- componentes de estilos para el uso de alertas -->
<script src="http://demo.itsolutionstuff.com/plugin/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://demo.itsolutionstuff.com/plugin/bootstrap-3.min.css"> @extends('TomoTest.inteligencia.base') @include('notification') @section('action-content')
<!-- Main content -->
<section class="content">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-header">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <h3 class="box-title">INSTRUCCIONES:</h3>
          <p>ELIJA LA OPCION CORRECTA RESPECTO A LA PREGUNTA EN CUESTION</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- /.box-header -->
    <div class="box-body">
      <div id="example2_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper form-inline dt-bootstrap">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <section id="dynamicTable">
              <table class="table table-bordered">

                @foreach($preguntas as $preguntas)
                <tr>
                  <th colspan="7">{{$preguntas->pregunta}}</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="hidden-xs">
                    A) {{$preguntas->opcion1}}
                    <input type="radio" class="flat" name="respuestaDeUsuario" value="1">
                  </td>
                  <td class="hidden-xs">
                    B) {{$preguntas->opcion2}}
                    <input type="radio" value="2" class="flat" name="respuestaDeUsuario">
                  </td>
                  <td class="hidden-xs">
                    C) {{$preguntas->opcion3}}
                    <input type="radio" value="3" class="flat" name="respuestaDeUsuario">
                  </td>
                  <td class="hidden-xs">
                    D) {{$preguntas->opcion4}}
                    <input type="radio" value="4" class="flat" name="respuestaDeUsuario">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <label for="">{{$preguntas->id}}</label>
                    <input type="hidden" name="candidato_id" value="{{$candidato->id}}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="pregunta_id" value="{{$preguntas->id}}">
                  </td>
                </tr>

                @endforeach
              </table>
            </section>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4"></div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" ">
         Finalizar
          </button>
          </form>
  </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>   
  <!-- /.box-body -->
</div>
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
  @endsection
```

Funiones utilizadas en el controlador empleado

```js
public function mostrarPreguntas($idTest){
        $preguntas=Pregunta::select('*')->where('test_id', '=', $idTest)->paginate(45);
        
        $respuesta=null;
        
        $authId = auth()->user()->id;
        $candidato = Candidato::find($authId);

        return view('testUser', ['preguntas' => $preguntas, 'respuesta' => $respuesta, 'candidato' => $candidato]);
    }
    
    public function guardarRespuestas(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'respuestaDeUsuario'=>'required', 'candidato_id'=>'required'
            , 'pregunta_id'=>'required'
        ]);
        Respuesta::create($request->all());
    }
```

................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 0):

Como todos los input radio tienen el mismo name, solo recibiras el ultimo

En el foreach integra un identificador de la tabla de preguntas

```
foreach($preguntas as $pregunta)
<input type="radio" name="respuesta_{{ $pregunta->id }}"/>
```

Asi recibiras una respuesta por pregunta

En el controlador de respuesta genera el mismo foreach

```
foreach($preguntas as $pregunta) {
if ($request->filled("respuesta{$pregunta->id}") {
  Respuesta::create(['key' => $value]);
}
}
```

Comment: La primer parte me funciono, ya lo revise con un echo, pero en la parte del controlador no supe adaptarlo, habia hecho algo parecedio pero fue para crear varias preguntas al momento de generar el test.


`$request->validate([ 'create.*.pregunta'=>'required', 'create.*.opcion1'=>'required', 
        'create.*.opcion2'=>'required','create.*.opcion3'=>'required', 'create.*.opcion4'=>'required', 
        'create.*.opcionCorrecta'=>'required', 'create.*.test_id'=>'required']);`
        
        `foreach ($request->create as $key => $value) {
            Pregunta::create($value);
        }`